# Accumulate multiple POSTs

Tags: php

I'm using autocomplete search in my project where user inputs an integer, submits it and it shows in same page what integer was passed in. I want users to be able - after submitting first integer - to submit another one, just can't figure out the solution. My code:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<p>Add integrent:</p><input type='text' name='sastavdalja'value=''class='auto'>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
<br/>
<p>Added integrents</p>
<?php

$int = $_POST["sastavdalja"];
echo $int;
```

Comment: Do you want to save the previously entered values and accumulate a list of them?

Comment: Yes that sounds right.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of the page before any output or html

```
<?php session_start();?>
```

then use this:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['int'][]=$_POST["sastavdalja"];
foreach($_SESSION['int'] as $int){
    echo $int;
}
```

Now you're saving each time the user posts something into a session array, and then you're looping through this array and printing each entry in it.